# 'Operation not permitted' error seen with */private/var/db folders in BigSur

Tags: backup, time-machine, permission

While backing up macOS BigSur machine, the Backup solution which I use throws 'Operation not permitted' error for   following following folders.

(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db/):
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/appinstalld/): (/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/installcoordinationd/)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/oah/)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/lockdown/)(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/DifferentialPrivacy) (/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/MobileIdentityService/)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/searchparty/)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/SystemKey)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/DifferentialPrivacy)
(/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/protected/trustd/private/)

I had given 'Full Disk Access' Permission to my backup solution.

Would like to understand the following:

1. What does above directory contains?
2. Why even with 'Full Disk Permission'( provided for my application), 'Operation not permitted' error is seen?.
3. Can these directories be excluded from backup? and does 'Time machine' do that?